# Android 5.0 - Declaring custom permissions in a module

Tags: android, android-studio, module, android-manifest, android-permissions

I have a module in Android Studio that I'm using across several apps (all signed with different keys) that handles GCM notifications.

In the GCM Client documentation they say to define package namespaced custom permissions:

```
<permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

and then again with the GCM receiver the `category` is set to the package name:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <category android:name="com.example.gcm" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Currently I have all these defined in the module's Manifest and it gets merged by gradle into the app manifest of whatever app is importing this module with a generic namespace for that module, and this has worked so far.

The problem is that since Android 5.0 custom permissions are matched against the keystore that the app was signed with. If you have one app with this module installed, it won't let you install another with the same module in it because the permissions conflict.

Is there a way to declare the `C2D_MESSAGE` permissions and the `BroadcastReceiver` within the module so that it doesn't need to be redefined in each app?

**[Update]**

I've tried using placeholders in the library's manifest with mixed results. Using `${applicationId}` results in that library's package name getting substituted rather than the consuming app's package name.

Reading [this and its related issues](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=143836) led me to use `${localApplicationId}` with it defined in the consuming app's build.gradle:

```
defaultConfig {
    manifestPlaceholders = [ localApplicationId:"com.testapp.client"]
    applicationId 'com.testapp.client'
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName '1.0'
}
productFlavors {
    flavor {
        applicationId "com.testapp.client.flavor"
        manifestPlaceholders = [ localApplicationId:"com.testapp.client.flavor"]
    }
}
```

results in error:

```
Error:(12, 22) Attribute uses-permission#${localApplicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE@name at AndroidManifest.xml:12:22 requires a placeholder substitution but no value for <localApplicationId> is provided.
```

Comment: You could see if manifest placeholders work in libraries, where the placeholders get reconciled when the app is compiled, not when the library is compiled.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know about these. They look very promising! Thanks. Will update if it works.

Comment: @CommonsWare It appears as though it resolves `${applicationId}` prior to the manifest merger, giving it the module's package-name/applicationId rather than the host app's ID.

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid of that. Alas, I don't have any better ideas.

Comment: @Affian did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: @NPike No sadly, I'm of the opinion that it's not currently possible. I ended up adding documentation to the library to add the custom permissions manually to the host application's manifest.

Comment: @Affian did you resolve this issue ? I'm too added GCM implementation in a module where I need to share in a few applications. If not, what was your final solution ?

Comment: @Gil At the time of writing, I believe it's not possible to reference the main application's `applicationId` from other modules. On the upside in the latest version of GCM the broadcast receiver is standard across all apps. So the receiver is declared in the Application's manifest and the service is declared in the module handling GCM.

Comment: So will it work with this kind of implementation? What should be the package name in the permission and receiver then?

Comment: The Application Manifest declares the reciever, see: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client

Then declare your `GcmListenerService` in the module.