# Duplicate permission in an SDK app

Tags: android

I have an SDK/Library that is used in several apps. I want to be able to send a secure broadcast from the SDK to the app implementing it, so I'm protecting my broadcast with a permission. My SDK defines the permission:

```
<permission android:name="my.sdk.permission.BROADCAST"
    android:label="my_sdk_permission"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="my.sdk.permission.BROADCAST"/>
```

And the app manifest has:

```
<receiver android:name="my.receiver.MyReceiver"
            android:permission="my.sdk.permission.BROADCAST"
            android:protectionLevel="signature"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="my.receiver.ACTION" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

However, with this setup I sometimes get errors installing multiple apps with the sdk:

> INSTALL_FAILED_DUPLICATE_PERMISSION perm=my.sdk.permission.BROADCAST
>   pkg=my.otherapp

I think what I need to do is on build make sure the permission is set to the package of the app implementing the SDK, but I'm not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Android 5.0+, the only way that 2+ apps can have a `<permission>` element for the same name is if the apps are signed by the same signing key.

In your case, simply remove all the permission stuff. The receiver is not exported, and so the permission will never come into play. You might consider also getting rid of the `<intent-filter>`, as that is not needed for a non-exported component. Just us an explicit `Intent`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But if I understand correctly and I remove the permission, any other app can catch my broadcast knowing the intent action?

Comment: @vkislicins: That's why you should get rid of the `<intent-filter>` and the action. Call `sendBroadcast()` with an explicit `Intent`. Or, switch to using some in-process event bus (e.g., `LocalBroadcastManager`, greenrobot's EventBus, Square's Otto). Do you have a scenario where this *must* be a system-level broadcast and it *must* use an implicit `Intent`? If you do, you can probably use manifest placeholders to have a per-app custom permission, though I have not tried that and it may limit your user's choices of IDE.

Comment: That last comment is extremely useful, thank you. I think I can achieve my goal while keeping things secure by moving my receiver from the app into the sdk, registering it in the sdk manifest and using explicit Intent to send a message. Then the apps implementing the sdk can extend the receiver and deal with the received message as they like.

Comment: Actually doesn't look like I can do this. Will have to go back to permissions path

Comment: @vkislicins: What is sending this broadcast? Is it the app itself (via your SDK)? Is it some separate app?

Comment: So the setup is quite similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30113223/android-5-0-declaring-custom-permissions-in-a-module - essentially what I want to do is catch a Push notification in my SDK, do some work, and re-throw to the app

Comment: The insecure way to do this would be to create a receiver in the app, and after SDK is done with Push - broadcast to the app. However, I cannot use the permissions for the reasons you've described and according to that link I've mentioned in the previous comment - trying to dynamically set the app package name in the manifest of the SDK is not supported either.

Comment: Can't use LocalBroadcastManager as the app might be in the background and can't really use an explicit intent as then I'll have to document the name of the class that the app implementing the sdk should create, which makes the whole security aspect quite dubious..

Comment: @vkislicins: You have two separate issues: catching the push message, and updating the app with the results of your work. For the latter, don't use a system broadcast with an implicit `Intent`. Use anything else: event bus, ordinary callback, `PendingIntent`, `ResultReceiver`, etc. "Can't use LocalBroadcastManager as the app might be in the background" -- I am not aware of that being a limitation, but you are welcome to use a different event bus.

Comment: @vkislicins: "can't really use an explicit intent" -- sure you can. Use `PackageManager` to find out what receiver to use. You could identify the non-exported receiver via an action string, though I'd probably opt for `<meta-data>`.

Comment: but what would prevent someone from creating an app with a receiver with the same `<meta-data>`?

Comment: @vkislicins: Your SDK is being compiled into an app. If you are sending a broadcast, you have a `Context`. When you call `getPackageName()` on that `Context`, you have the application ID of the app using your SDK. When you go into `PackageManager`, get the `ApplicationInfo` of that specific app, and find the specific receiver of interest. Then, use an explicit `Intent` for that receiver. Using system broadcasts for communications within an app is wasteful, which is why I have been counselling against it, but you can certainly use an explicit `Intent` if you insist on system broadcasts.

Comment: I understand that the a system broadcast should be avoided, but I'm not sure how else to send a message to the app from my GCM service. System broadcast is the only solution I can see that can be registered declaratively and doesn't require unregistering to avoid leaks.If I use callback, local broadcast, result receiver - I'm supposed to unregister those when activity is stopped - so when the push message comes in, there will be no listener on the app level to handle it after the sdk service is done with it. Or am i missing something really obvious?

Comment: @vkislicins: You are assuming that the "callback, local broadcast, result receiver" are being registered by an activity. If that's a problem, document that problem, and rely on your SDK users to implement things as they see fit. Another possibility is to require them to have an `Application` object that implements some SDK-defined interface, and you call a method on that interface to deliver them the message. Then, it's up to them to route that message accordingly within their app.